# How to pass values from HTML Table to a child popup window edit it and return to Parent

Tags: spring, jsp, controller, popupwindow

what I need is :  in a jsp page a table contains several rows. Each row contains some data,i dont want to display the data, but instead provide a link to view the data and also one can edit it also. I found several solution to display the data, but i am not getting how to edit the data and then return back the data. I found this solution in the forum quite close to my problem [How to pass values from HTML Table to JQuery Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689420/how-to-pass-values-from-html-table-to-jquery-dialog), but this also only displays the data but doesnt lets you edit it. I am using Spring as framework and jsp for display. Please help to find the solution.

Regards
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is - in the table in last column give a link call edit and in the link add the id of the row in the data attribute like this -

< a href="#" data-id="id-of-row-in-db" onclick="editPopup(id-of-row-in-db)">Edit</a>

now in editPopup() function you have id of the row so after popup is displayed you get the row value from the db with ajax call and put the values in text boxes which is editable.

And once  the user edit the value and click update button you send the new values from popup with the id and update the records in the database with this id.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, i 'll try the out the approach and let you know if it is successful.Thanks again for the reply.